# How can I know previous action name from controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I know previous action name from controller action for both post and get(I already know that UrlRefer only works for get)? Thanks all.

example: The page1 is submitted to action2 in controller. The page1 page action name is action1. I want to know that these came from action1 within action2 in controller.

Comment: please share your work done so far so i can help

Comment: If you're posting to Action2, why not just have a property in your model for PrevAction that gets passed into the new action? So on Action1 you have a hidden input whose value = "Action1" that gets posted to Action2?

Comment: Yes. I know this way. But I want to know that the MVC framework can support for this.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be a Session object set to the current action.  Each time you move, update the Session object.

Example:

```
public ActionResult Action1()
{
    var previousAction = Session["LastAction"].ToString();
    ...
    Session["LastAction"] = "Action1";
}

public ActionResult Action2()
{
    var previousAction = Session["LastAction"].ToString();
    ...
    Session["LastAction"] = "Action2";
}
```

If you want to destroy the session at any point, here is the code to do so.

```
Session.Remove("LastAction");
```

Another way to do this would be to pass the Action name into your model and hide it within a hidden field so that you can keep it for however long you want.

Comment: and how about destroying the sessions. Or you gonna keep these sessions throughout the application.

Comment: Destroying them is simple.  Will show in post.  And it all depends on whether @zanhtet wants to keep it constantly going or not.

Comment: I didn't ask syntax to remove session, but my question is when to destroy as my manager always says using sessions is a bad practice to code.

Comment: Session isn't always the best practice, yes.  But it also depends on how long you intend on using it and for what.  Query strings are good too but as I said before, it does muck up the URL.  I use both personally during development.  It mostly depends on the situation more than anything else.